# Haskell list comprehension for finding primes

Tags: haskell, syntax, syntax-error, list-comprehension, primes

I'm trying to find all the primes less than some integer `n` as concisely as possible, using list comprehensions. I'm learning Haskell, and this is just an exercise. I'd like to write something like:

```
isqrt :: Integral a => a -> a   
isqrt = floor . sqrt . fromIntegral

primes :: Integral a => a -> [a]  
primes n = [i | i <- [1,3..n], mod i k /= 0 | k <- primes (isqrt i)]
```

which of course doesn't work. Is there a way to have a list comprehension inside a list comprehension?

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
exercise-99-1.hs:138:39: Not in scope: `k'

exercise-99-1.hs:138:46:
    Illegal parallel list comprehension: use -XParallelListComp

exercise-99-1.hs:138:68: Not in scope: `i'
```

BUT - I wasn't really expecting the syntax to even be legit :-)

The intent was to translate as directly as possible: *" `primes n` = the set of odd integers `i` less than `n` such that `i` is not divisible by any `k`, for all `k` in the set: `primes (isqrt i)`"* - more or less. (I hope I got that right?)

Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't work is extremely unhelpful. Post the error.

Comment: Could you put that error into the body of your post? Thanks.

Comment: here's one: [`[n | n<-[2..545], []<-[[j | i<-[2..n-2], j<-[i*i,i*i+i..n], j==n]]]`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37103662/programming-haskell-code-list-of-primes/37148656#37148656) - both trial division and kind of a sieve of Eratosthenes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some progress with the following:

```haskell
primes :: Integral a => a -> [a]  
primes 2 = [2]  
primes n = 2:[i | i <- [3,5..n], all (\k -> if (mod i k /= 0) then True else False) 
                                     (primes (isqrt i))]
```

Is there a shorter way to write the lambda predicate?

*edit:* Yes, there is, thanks to the remarks in the comments!

```haskell
primes :: Integral a => a -> [a]  
primes 2 = [2]  
primes n = 2:[i | i <- [3,5..n], all ((/= 0) . mod i) (primes (isqrt i))]
```

Comment: Never say `if ... then True else False`.  Instead just say the `...` part: `\k -> mod i k /= 0`

Comment: You can also make it point-free, if that's your thing:
`((/= 0) . mod i)`

Comment: Even clearer is to define a separate function: `divisible i = (== 0) . mod i`, and then instead of your lambda function, have `(not . divisible i)`

Comment: What is the reason for never saying "if... then True else False"?

Comment: @Frank Because it is totally redundant, so it just makes the code less clear.

Comment: @Frank: Because the conditional expression already evaluates to `True` or `False`. The `if` statement is completely redundant and clutters things up.

Comment: @Frank you meant to say, *without* the `primes 2 = [2]` line. Which really should've been `primes 1 = []`. :)

Answer (score 0):

your code,

```
primes n = [i | i <- [1,3..n], mod i k /= 0 
              | k <- primes (isqrt i)]
```

is interpreted as *parallel* list comprehension; i.e. instead of combining the two generators in the usual *nested* fashion, they are combined in parallel:

```
primes n = [i | (i,k) <- zip [i | i <- [1,3..n], mod i k /= 0]
                                    -- not in scope: k ^
                             [k | k <- primes (isqrt i)] ]
                                  -- not in scope: i ^
```

Instead, to express what you intended, it can be written as

```
primes 1 = []
primes n = 2:[i | i <- [3,5..n], and [mod i k /= 0 | k <- primes (isqrt i)]]
```

thus having a list comprehension inside a list comprehension - but as part of a guard, not generator. The function `and :: [Bool] -> Bool` makes this possible.

---

Incidentally, calling `primes` recursively for *each* new candidate `i` makes it run slow, with run times growing too fast, [empirically](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analysis_of_algorithms#Empirical_orders_of_growth):

```
 > length $ primes 10000     -- => 1229    (0.50 secs)

 > length $ primes 20000     -- => 2262    (1.40 secs)

 > logBase (2262/1229) (1.4/0.5)      -- => 1.6878      ~ n^1.69

 > length $ primes 40000     -- => 4203    (4.07 secs)

 > logBase (4203/2262) (4.07/1.4)     -- => 1.7225      ~ n^1.72
```

Optimal trial division usually runs at *~ n<sup>1.4..1.45</sup>*, list-based sieve of Eratosthenes at *~ n<sup>1.2..1.25</sup>* and, if optimally implemented on mutable arrays, at *~ n<sup>1.0..1.1</sup>* (with *n* the number of primes produced, *not* the upper limit).