# Unexpected parallel statement in a list comprehension Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, list-comprehension

I am getting this error, I'm trying to implement a bloom filter

```
Unexpected parallel statement in a list comprehension
Use ParallelListComp
```

from this line of code below

```
addDB db idx = (last z) where z = db:[ setTrue  udb i  | udb <- z | i <- idx ]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6085347/haskell-list-comprehension-question

Comment: You may have meant `[setTrue udb i | udb <- z, i <- idx]`, but if you wanted this to work more like a `zip` then you'll need to enable the `ParallelListComp` extension when compiling your code.  The regular list comprehension acts like a cartesian product instead of a `zip`, going through every combination of elements from `z` and from `idx`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just needed to add

```
{-# LANGUAGE ParallelListComp #-}
```

Thanks for pointing that out bheklilr

Answer (score 4):

Did you really mean to use a [parallel list comprehension](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/5.00/docs/set/parallel-list-comprehensions.html) there? To quote the [Haskell 2010 Report](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/haskell2010/haskellch3.html#x8-420003.11), a (normal) list comprehension has the form `[e | q_1, ..., q_n]` where each qualifier `q_i` is either a generator of the form `p <- e`, a local binding, or a boolean guard. If you intended one of these, you should use a comma and not a pipe to separate the qualifiers in your list comprehension.