# programming haskell code: List of primes

Tags: haskell, list-comprehension, primes

My task is to create a list of primes but only with the following information:

-The list has to be infinite
-I have to check up primes for `n > 1`
-If there is a variable `2 <= k < n-2`, which divides `n`,then it is no prime, if it does not divide `n`, it is
-No function!

So I started writing a code like this:

```
primes = [n| n<-[2,3..],k<-[2,3..], if (k>=2) && (k<=(n-2))
            then if n `mod` k /= 0 then n else return ()
            else return ()  ]
```

But then appears the following error : "Couldn't match expected type ‘Bool’ with actual type"

It's because of the `return ()`, but I don't know how to replace this `return`.

I hope for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you had a function:

```
isPrime :: Int -> Bool
```

which returned True for primes and False otherwise. Then you could define:

```
primes = [ n | n <- [2..], isPrime n ]
```

Using the function `all`, you could write `isPrime` like this:

```
isPrime n = all (\a -> mod n a /= 0) [2..n-1]
```

`all f xs` returns True if `f` applied to every member of `xs` is True. So `n` is prime if for all elements in [2..n-1], `mod n a /= 0`, i.e. a does not divide n.

Some more examples of the `all` function:

```
all even [2,4,10,12]       -- True
all (\x -> x > 0) [4,-5,6] -- False
all (\xs -> length xs > 0) [ [3], [4,5], [-4] ] -- True
all (\x -> x*x < 0) []     -- True
```

You can come up with the definition of `all` yourself by using the standard template for recursion on lists:

```
all f []     =  ...
all f (x:xs) =  ...
```

Comment: Thank you I'm very grateful for your help!!

Answer (score 0):

It should be *2 <= k **<=** n-2*, otherwise 4 would be prime (with the ***<***).

Without functions, it can be written as

```
[n | n<-[2..], []<-[[i | i<-[2..div n 2], rem n i==0]]]            -- or, even,
[n | n<-[2..], []<-[[j | i<-[2..n-2], j<-[i*i, i*i+i..n], j==n]]]  -- no `i` dividing `n`
```

The last code snippet is remarkable for being both a trial division and a sieve of Eratosthenes working through addition only (becoming the true sieve when the computational redundancies are discovered and eliminated through rearrangement and sharing of repeated calculations).

To your question specifically, `return` is out of place there. Test expressions in list comprehensions are simply expressions of type `Bool`. The `False` result means rejection of the currently generated value; `True` means acceptance — and therefore inclusion in the list of results.

Another thing is, repeated failed testing of repeatedly generated values means *infinite  looping*, when for all values of `k` above `n-2` (generated by `k<-[2..]` without end) your test `(k>=2) && (k<=(n-2))` will *always fail* (and cause the next `k` being generated, and the next one, and the next...).

Instead of testing, we stop the generation after `n-2` altogether, with `[2..n-2]`, so the test condition always holds *by construction* — and were it would fail, those values of `k` are not generated at all, in the first place.